# Skiasharp rotate image running out of memory

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am using Xamarin Forms to create a mobile app that has several instruments on it.  Think of a car dashboard.   I am updating the instruments from another source every 100ms. Take for instance a compass, as you turn my compass instrument turns to the correct position.  So I am rotating my compass with the following code:

```
        public static SKBitmap Rotate(SKBitmap bitmap, double angle)
    {
        var rotated = new SKBitmap(bitmap.Height, bitmap.Width);

        using (var surface = new SKCanvas(rotated))
        {
            surface.RotateDegrees((float)angle, rotated.Width / 2, rotated.Height / 2);
            surface.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0);
        }

        return rotated;
    }
```

The problem is that over time, the app runs out of memory.  When I add more instruments to rotate (like speedometer), it crashes faster.

I verified that without this call the app runs fine.   It seems there must be a better way to rotate a bitmap in place rather than create a new canvas and draw to it just to be drawn again on the real canvas.  Any thoughts or direction here?  Thank you.

Comment: if that's all you need, why not just use the Rotation property of the Image control?

Comment: There will be other kinds of rotation and also moving x/y axis.  As well as transparent layers to form one instrument.  So Skiasharp seemed like it would be a good solution.

Comment: you can Translate the Image control, too.  Note that your Rotate method creates a new Bitmap every time it is called.  If I had a better understanding of what you're trying to do I might be able to offer a better suggestion

Comment: When you say Image Control, are you talking about the standard Xamarin Image or a Skiasharp object?

Comment: yes, those properties existing on VisualElement, so every XF control has them